# Select option Onchange method- if the object is there then update it or else create a new one

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

```
const [skills,setSkills] = useState([
    {
      name:"",
      skill_type:"",
      level_type:""
    }
  ])

 const handleChangeSkillType =(e,index)=>{
    const primary = e.target.getAttribute('dataskill')
    const newstate=skills.map((skill)=> skill.name === primary ? {...skill,skill_type:e.target.value} : {name:primary,skill_type:e.target.value,level_type:""} )
    setSkills(newstate)
  }


------return statement---------

{step1response.skills.must_have.slice(0, 5).map((t,index) => (
                <tr key={t}>
                  <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" onChange={(e)=>handleSkills(e,index)}/>
                  </td>
                  <td value={t.name}>{t}</td>
                  <td>
                    <select name="skill_type" dataskill={t} value={t.type} className="custom-input p1" onChange={(e)=>handleChangeSkillType(e,index)}>
                      <option>Select</option>
                      <option value="Must Have" selected>Must have</option>
                      <option value="Nice to have">Nice to have</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
```

I am trying to fill up my skills array...In onchange method i want if there is a skill name that matches the attribute in select then update the skill_type or else create a new one...but my on change method is not working as planned...can someone tell what is wrong in this?

Comment: yeah..but thats just returning {name:"",skill_type:"",level_type:""} because its not creating a new one..just returning empty skill

Comment: Would you show the sample of `skills` to figure out its structure, as your `return` part seems a bit confusing - based on `t.name`, `t` is expected to be an object, but you pass it as a child to `<td>` which should throw an error.

Comment: If you want to conditionally add or update an array element then you'll need to first search your `skills` state if the skill name is already there to know whether you can simply copy existing state and append new element to skills array or if you need to map the skills array and update a specific element (*likely via index*).

Comment: It looks like your return statement might need some review: [1] `t` is an object and cannot be used as key for the `<tr>` nor as content of a `<td>`, [2] in the `<select>` element you set the attribute "value" equal to `t.type` but `t` has no "type" attribute (did you mean `t.skill_type`?). Moreover, in the `handleChangeSkillType` function you assign to the variable "primary" `e.target.getAttribute('dataskill')` which, is a skill object, not just the skill name; the comparison `skill.name === primary` will always be `false`; did you mean `skill.name === primary.name`?